# European phone formating with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

With rails, I can format a number into a US phone number with [number_to_phone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_phone)

I'am using using european phone format, which means that I want to group numbers with the following format, `n` is a variable:

```
(n*x) xxx-xxx
```

Some examples

```
6365555796 => (6365) 555-796

665555796  => (665) 555-796
```

How to achieve that with the latest rails 3.0.7?

Comment: Can you please give a couple of examples for better understanding? Specifically for the section (n*x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about so:

```
def to_phone(num)
   groups = num.to_s.scan(/(.*)(\d{3})(\d{3})/).flatten
   "(#{groups.shift}) #{groups.shift}-#{groups.shift}"
end


irb(main):053:0> to_phone 318273612
=> "(318) 273-612"
irb(main):054:0> to_phone 3182736122
=> "(3182) 736-122"
irb(main):055:0> to_phone 31827361221
=> "(31827) 361-221"
```

...

Answer (score 2):

i think you have to write your own method for this there is no built-in method in my knowledge for it and i think you can achieved the desired thing by writing apropriate regular expression for that.

have you tried validate_format_for with: there u can write specific regualr expression for it [see this] http://ruby-forum.com/topic/180192 for writing your own helper for it

check this gem here is what you need http://github.com/floere/phony

Comment: afridi, why don't you move these comments into your answer, to make it more complete and readable?

Answer (score 0):

A faster approach:

```
def to_european_phone_format(number)
  "(#{number/10**6}) #{number/10**3%10**3}-#{number%10**3}"
end
```

Comment: nice ;) isn't "%10**6" redundant here?

Comment: Yeah, it was. Corrected. Thanks :)